# Tips for Service broker pattern to prevent concurrency issues

Tags: sql-server, service-broker

1. A single process in my ASP.NET Website will be fired from different locations at ~ same time.
2. Trying to use SQL Server Broker to Queue the requests and execute one by one.
3. Enabled SQL Broker and created a Queue and Service in the database. On receiving a request; I begin a dialog conversation using only the 1 Service and log the conversation token in a table.
4. Have written an activated procedure to access the data passed into Queue and Initiate processing.
5. End conversation inside activated procedure after Processing is complete.

I have doubts regarding the pattern I am  following. The conversation does not get closed correctly. In some examples; I have seen an Initiator and Target Queue pattern where conversation is closed at both endpoints. Please help me to figure out the pattern needed in this case.

**UPDATE**

Sorry for not updating; got busy with some other work. I changed to using 2 each of Queues(Initiator and Target), Services and the corresponding Activated procs.
 The connections get closed properly now. When we insert into the Target queue while 1st request is being processed; do we need to specify any setting or command to ensure that 1st request gets completed before starting the 2nd one?

Comment: Is the only question/issue you have that the conversation is not closing? If so, is it being closed on either side (i.e. initiator, target)? What does sys.conversation_endpoints say about that conversation handle?

Comment: @BenThul   The request endpoints get closed and are removed after receiving End Dialog message from the target. I read that target endpoints get closed after ~ 30 min as per system behavior.  Updated question.

Comment: Do not use a conversation just to pass a single message. This is a common anti-pattern in service broker and it's massively wasteful. Create a single conversation that you keep open indefinitely. If completion feedback is required, send a response message to that effect. An open conversation does not take up any resources save a negligible amount of storage on a data page, and there's no real reason to ever end it unless the service stops existing or an error occurs.